# Why quick sort is always slower than bubble sort in my case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

They use same array:

QUICK SORT Time: 3159 miliseconds (array length 10K)

Bubble SORT Time: 1373 miliseconds (array length 10K)

I'm trying to compare time of the sorting using quick and bubble sort algoritms. I use the array with 10K different random numbers sorted in random order for both functions. But for some reason bubble sort is always sort array faster than quick sort, even if average time complexity of bubble sort is worse than average time complexity of quick sort. Why bubble sort algorithms slower than quick sort algorithm in my case? (I tried different lengths of array, from 10 to 10K)

Thats my quick sort function

```
let quickSort = (arr) => {
    if (arr.length <= 1) {
        return arr
    }
    const pivot = arr[0]
    const rest = arr.slice(1);
    let left = [],
        right = [];
    rest.forEach(el => el > pivot ? right = [...right, el] : left = [...left, el]);
    return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)];
}
```

And that's my bubble sort function

```
let bubbleSort = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let s = i + 1; s < arr.length; s++) {
            if (arr[s] < arr[i]) {
                let a = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[s]
                arr[s] = a;
            }       
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Comment: Quicksort is making lots of copies, bubble sort is swapping in place.

Comment: `right = [...right, el]` this leads to an O(n²) operation overall per step - you are doing way too much copying.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oooh, that's right, after I changed it to concatenate it works so faster. Now: QUICK SORT Time: 32 miliseconds. 
Bubble SORT Time: 1556 miliseconds.Thank you :)

Comment: Quicksort doesn't need to copy at all, you can make an implementation, which just sorts in-place, if you want to be fast. PS: i'm not too sure what your original quicksort's order is, somewhere between O(n²) and O(n²log(n)), but it's too late here, i'm starting make mistakes and miss simple things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @Barmar said, Quicksort is making a lot of copies.

Also, each **spread operator** (the 3 dots operator) has a complexity of O(n) as **it iterates through the whole array** (like a simple *for* loop) which might also makes the algorithm slower.

Comment: ooh, now understood why it was so slow, now quick sort do not make copies but just concatenate arrays so now it works a lot faster than bubble sort. Thank you!